# C#: Access Enum from another class

Tags: c#, enums

I know I can declare an `enum` directly in the Namespace so everyone can access it being in the same namespace.

But can I declare it in a class to access from other class:

```cs
public class Class1
{
    public enum Mode { Selected, New }  
}

public class Class2
{
    var class1 = new ();
    // Set the Mode
    class1.Mode = Mode.Selected;
}
```

Is it possible to use `enums` without declaring it in the namespace?

Comment: Really didnt understand you there... you can access classes defined inside classes only from objects, just as you are doing, so whats the problem?

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to avoid using the namespace qualifier? Also, `The namespace area of a class` isn't very clear.

Comment: In my opinion you should really define an enum in its own file. That way you would not have nested classes to reference.

Comment: @froeschli I agree with the spirit of your comment, but you don't have to put the enum in a separate file to keep it from being nested inside of the class.

Comment: @David Lively I learned OOP by studying Java. I guess it kind of stuck having a separate file per class/enum.

Comment: @froeschil its typically good practice to keep them separated in separate files, but there are exceptions. Java isn't the only language that enforces that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to do what is described below it will not work...

```
    public class MyClass1
    {
        private enum Mode { New, Selected };
        public Mode ModeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass2
    {
        public MyClass2()
        {
            var myClass1 = new MyClass1();

            //this will not work due to protection level
            myClass1.ModeProperty = MyClass1.Mode.
        }
    }
```

What you could do however is below, which will work...

```
    public interface IEnums
    {
        public enum Mode { New, Selected };
    }

    public class MyClass1
    {
        public IEnums.Mode ModeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass2
    {
        public MyClass2()
        {
            var myClass1 = new MyClass1();

            //this will work
            myClass1.ModeProperty = IEnums.Mode.New;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Lisa I edited the answer to be more inline with I think what you are trying to do...if not...then the other answer is in the history...:)

Comment: So do I, in addition to Idan Shechter's comment "I get interface cannot declare types when using this code".

Comment: @AaronMcIver Interface cannot contain enums.

Comment: even though this is the accepted answer this is unnecessary. following your first example you could just make it public and it would work, otherwise you could declare the enum outside the class, effectively declaring on the same namespace, and it would work as well. I got curious regarding the interface, why declare on the interface?

Answer (score 23):

You can declare an enum outside of a class:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Entry1,
        Entry2,
    }
}
```

And then you can add `using MyNamespace;` where it needs to be used.

Comment: The OP said *"Is this somehow possible without using namespace area?"*

Comment: @cdhowie: I was confused by some of the wording in the question, so I thought she was trying to avoid the need to fully-qualify the class name. Your answer and mine basically fully show how enums can be declared, so one way or another the question should be answered :-)

Comment: I see, yeah that's a possible interpretation.  The wording is definitely not clear.  :)

Comment: Wow, that was the simplest of the solution I had found!

Answer (score 10):

Aaron's answer is very nice but I believe there is a much better way to do this:

```
public static class class1
{
    public void Run()
    {
        class2.Mode mode = class2.Mode.Selected;

        if (mode == class2.Mode.Selected)
        {
            // Do something crazy here...
        }
    }
}

public static class class2
{
    public enum Mode
    { 
        Selected, 
        New
    } 
}
```

No point over complicating this. It is a simple task.

All the Best

Chris.

Comment: I get the " interface cannot declare types" error when I used the accepted solution, however this worked pretty well!

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

```
class2.Mode = class2.Mode.Selected
```

But note that you can't have a nested type defined that has the same name as one of the outer class' members, so this code will not compile.  Either the enum or the property will need to be named something else.  Your class name and variable name conflict too, making this a bit more complex.

To make this a more generic answer, if you have this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public SomeEnum SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public enum SomeEnum {
        Hello, World
    }
}
```

Then this code will assign an enum value to the property:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.SomeProperty = Foo.SomeEnum.Hello;
```

Comment: When I type class2. the Mode enum does not appear in Intellisense so it seems NOT to work. As I described, I want to set Mode on an INSTANCE not via classname.Mode.

Comment: @Lisa: That's because you have named your variable the same name as the class.  The symbols overlap, so the compiler assumes you are referring to the variable.  Change the name of your variable, or the name of the class.  See my extra example code for the proper syntax you will have to use after renaming one of them.

Comment: @Elisabeth I had the same problem. The explanation I finally found really is this simple: enum is part of the class, not part of a class instance. As you already commented above, using a property is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving my issue by changing it to a namespace accessor, found by utilizing Intellisense. I thought the enum was in the class, not just the namespace. If it was in the class, I would recommend moving it out of the class.

```
namespace ABC.XYZ.Contracts
{
  public class ChangeOrder : BaseEntity, IAuditable
  {
     ...
  }

  public enum ContractorSignatureType
  {
    A,
    B,
    V
  }
}
```

`ContractorSignatureType = Contracts.ContractorSignatureType.B,`

Answer (score 0):

The question ain't very clear and each answer seem to approach on a subjective way so here is my take:

- When we have a class that requires unique `enum` we can declare it on the same class, it will be accessible on all person instances.

```cs
namespace MyApp.Models
{
   public class Person
   {
      public AgeGroup ageGroup;

      public enum AgeGroup { Baby, Child, Teen, Adult, Senior}
   }
}
```

Declaration:

```cs
using MyApp.Models;
(...)
Person p = new();
p.ageGroup = Person.AgeGroup.Baby;
```

But you can see that it gets a bit verbose with `Person.AgeGroup.Baby`.

- Alternatively we can declare the `enum` in the same namespace as the class we wanna use, if unique to the class preferably in the same file, just below the class but that's absolutely optional.

This method lets the enum be used all over the namespace where its declared.

```cs
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public AgeGroup ageGroup;
    }

    public enum AgeGroup { Baby, Child, Teen, Adult, Senior}
}
```

Declaration:

```cs
using MyApp.Models;
(...)
Person p = new();
p.ageGroup = AgeGroup.Baby;
```

> Note that the namespace is the same as the Person class so no aditional namespace is required.

- When the `enum` is used "everywhere" on your project(s) you can declare it on a more accessible namespace, for example your main project namespace:

```cs
namespace MyApp
{
    //this could be your "App.cs" file with the enum declared after the class
    //or just a new "SomeEnums.cs" file
    public enum Mode {A, B}
}
```

Declaration:

```cs
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class Test
    {
        Mode mode = Mode.A;
    }
}
```

> Note that in the previous example I declared on the MyApp namespace but I used on child/nested namespace MyApp.ViewModels.

- Or declare the enum on a dedicated namespace for helpers, I use this namespace to declare extention methods, global enums and any other static helpers:

```cs
namespace MyApp.Helpers
{
    public enum Mode { A, B}
}
```

Declaration:

```cs
using MyApp.Helpers;
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Test
    {
        Mode mode = Mode.A;
    }
}
```