# How to access ENUM which is declared in a separate class - C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following code:

```
class EmployeeFactory
{
        public enum EmployeeType
        {
                ManagerType,
                ProgrammerType,
                DBAType
        }
}
```

I want to access this in MAIN class (Program).  I have written the following code. IT WORKS. But I want to know how I can access the ENUM without instantiating the class -- Means ENUM is like a static variable (Class Level Variable) ? Any help ?

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(EmployeeFactory.EmployeeType.ProgrammerType);  // WORKS WELL
        }
}
```

or do I need to write it this way?

```
EmployeeFactory ef = new EmployeeFactory();
ef.EmployeeType.ProgrammerType
```

Comment: What is the problem? You can just refer to the enum as you do in your question. What else would you want to do?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You say that your Console.WriteLine() code works. That code does not instantiate an instance of your class. What is the problem?

Comment: You answered your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access it simply using the class.

```
EmployeeFactory.EmployeeType.ProgrammerType
```

The enum is part of the class, not part of a class instance.

Comment: How ? Is it sonmething like "STATIC" variable so that i can put <ClassName>.<MemberName> ? It belongs to the CLASS instead of OBJECT ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes that is correct.  The enum type belongs to the class not to an instance of the class.

Comment: The enum is part of the class, not part of a class instance - This is what i need.

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to know how I can access the ENUM without instantiating the class

The original way you're accessing this enum

`Console.WriteLine(EmployeeFactory.EmployeeType.ProgrammerType);`

already accomplishes that; you **are** accessing the enum without instantiating the class.

Answer (score -2):

try something like this ...

```
    public interface IEnums
    {
        public enum Mode { New, Selected };
    }

    public class MyClass1
    {
        public IEnums.Mode ModeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass2
    {
        public MyClass2()
        {
            var myClass1 = new MyClass1();

            //this will work
            myClass1.ModeProperty = IEnums.Mode.New;
        }
    }
```

or
  you can directly access like this....

```
 EmployeeFactory.EmployeeType.ProgrammerType
```

i hope it will helps you

Comment: It seems like you copied this from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4444048/663899. Also, this doesn't seem to work for me, I get an error "interfaces can't declare types".