# working with custom Types to replaces string parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, properties, webforms

if you don't need the backround for this question then skip to the question below.

as you could see in first code block , I am using constants as parameters passed to the Style Dictionary.

since I know (by now), that types are vastly used in `.net`,  i would like to find out,  how to specify that the dictionary will accept parameter passed as dedicated types, rather than a `string` type.

and that will also  be another small lesson for me, about types .

```C#
                         //string                //string 
html.StyleDict.Add(Stl.Prop.BgColor, Stl.Vals.Clr.Aquamarine);
```

up until now, I was passing it (the style dictionary) strings,  to be used as parameters, so i could make it do the job, while keeping it simple... as I am still fresh with `.net`, and back then... when I've created this class, I couldn't even think of learning what `types` are, or how to work with them .

so ...as for this scenario, the implementation and usage **should be quite a simple task** (for some of you ...well actually most of you if not all(: ) to convet implementation by using custom types instead of strings .

### Question is : How To Create the style class?

... so eventually it will be passing strings for that C# styling task, but the dictionary will allow you to pass parameters as types of `style`,  that's because the html css styling is done through code behind is via strings values. though I would use my custom Style class when populating  the style dictionary.

```C#
                     //styleType                //styleType 
html.StyleDict.Add(Stl.Prop.BgColor, Stl.Vals.Clr.Aquamarine);
```

**for example.**

This is the class i am using to make alternation of backround for element  
by using a loop that generates html markup , so i am passing in the counter of loop along with other style properties for current element in the loop

(a little off topic but i had to give a usage example to ilustrate the meaning of this question)

...also that's the spot where the dictionary of style comes to use.

```C#
public sealed class html
{
      //  current Typless Dictionary
    public static Dictionary<string, string> StyleDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        // future dictionary (: , naturally it wouldnt work with the parameters as it is now (see relevant Styles Class
    public static Dictionary<Styles.Prop, Styles.Vals> StyleDict = new Dictionary<Stl.Prop, Stl.Vals>();
    public static string DynamicStyle_Generator
    (
        int LoopCounter = -1,
        Dictionary<string, string> StyleAttributeDict = null
    )
    {
        string BaseStyle = "", Terminator = "'", BgCol = "";

        StringBuilder StylerSB = new StringBuilder();


        BgCol = "";
        bool bgcolAlternator;

            if (LoopCounter >= 0)
            {
                LoopCounter++ ;
                bgcolAlternator = (RowCounter % 2) == 0;

                    if (bgcolAlternator)
                        BgCol = "#70878F";

                    else BgCol = "#E6E6B8";
             }

        BaseStyle = string.Format("style='background-color:{0};", BgCol);
        return string.Concat(BaseStyle, StyleDict, Terminator);

    }
```

```C#
        Lsts.StlsDict.Add(Stl.Prop.BgColor, Stl.Vals.Clr.Aquamarine);

        public Dictionary<Stl.Prop, Stl.Vals> StlsDict = new Dictionary<Stl.Prop, Stl.Vals>();


    public static class Styles
    {

        public sealed class Props
        {
            public static string pBgUrl1(string fileName)
            {
                return "url('images/" + fileName + "')";
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Specifies the HTML backgroundimage style.
            /// </summary>
            public static readonly string BgColor = "Background-Color ",

            /// <summary>
            ///     Specifies the HTML backgroundimage style.
            /// </summary>
            BackgroundImage = "Background-image ",

            /// <summary>
            ///     Specifies the HTML bordercollapse style.
            /// </summary>
            BorderCollapse = "BorderCollapse ",

            /// <summary>
            ///     Specifies the HTML bordercolor style.
            ///</summary>
            BorderColor = "BorderColor ",

            /// <summary>
            ///     Specifies the HTML borderstyle style.
            ///     </summary>        
            BorderStyle = "BorderStyle ",
     }


        public sealed class Vals
        {

            public class fontNames
            {
                public const string Aharoni = "Aharoni",
                                    Andalus = "Andalus",
                                    AngsanaNew = "Angsana New",
                                    AngsanaUPC = "AngsanaUPC",
                                    Aparajita = "Aparajita";
            }


            public class Color
            {
                public const string AliceBlue = "AliceBlue";
                public const string AntiqueWhite = "AntiqueWhite";
                public const string Aqua = "Aqua";
                public const string Aquamarine = "Aquamarine";
                public const string Azure = "Azure";
            }
       }
}
```

another way i could use to have my own type passed( condition is to use same dictionary)
only thing i could come up with is using default values set to parameters

```
while writing this , i could have thought of this actually 


Dictionary<T,T> StyleDict = new Dictionary<T, T>();
```

than just convert to string ! (not working )

```
    public static string DynamicStyle_Generator
    (
        int LoopCounter = -1,
        Dictionary<Styles.Props, Styles.Vals.Color> StyleColor = null
        Dictionary<Styles.Props, Styles.Vals.fontNames> StylefontNames = null
    )
    {
```

here there's no need unless you want the fonts but not the color you will have to be uncomfertable by calling like this

```
DynamicStyle_Generator(counterhere , null, DictionaryOfFonts);
```

otherwise

```C#
DynamicStyle_Generator(counterhere , DictionartyColors, DictionaryOfFonts);
```

then this will do it's job regardless to the values same way (null or not)

```
        return string.Concat(BaseStyle, DictionartyColors, DictionaryOfFontsm, Terminator);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a case of over-engineering.  There is a reason that `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl` exposes its `Style` property which internally works with strings for both the keys and the values.  You are wanting to supply a list of constants for keys, which is ok,  a list of constants for the values won't.

Comment: i could think of that idea , and i did hav my Doubt. still i wanted to make it as a practice , as you can see i already have it working as it is , though i wanted to find a solution to my question like a kind of a C# `Types` Quiz see comments ...

Comment: Practice is a good thing!  One pointer though in terminology -- it seems that you are getting the term 'Generics' and 'Types' confused.  A class or method that uses angle braces is denoting Generics -- like `Dictionary<string, string>`.  All objects inherit from System.Object, which provides a method GetType() which returns a Type object describing the object.  The Type class is used primarily with Reflection.

Comment: i really really did not want that to happen , (don't get me wrong i do respect your opinion) but i would have liked to avoid it but rethinking it i could come up with one more idea that will then involve mr'  `reflection` . closed as you were teribly right (: thanks you did help alot no C# code was even  needed in your answer (:

Answer (score 0):

An enum in C#  is used to represent a set of fixed distinct values

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20805/Enhancing-C-Enums

based on your comment, i think this is what you are looking for:
http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2006/01/07/434774.aspx

from the above link:

```
public enum Colors
{
   red, blue, green
}

Set<Colors> sc = new Set<Colors>();
sc.Add(Colors.red);
sc.Add(Colors.green);

Set<Colors> sc2 = new Set<Colors>();
sc2.Add(Colors.blue);

sc.Add(sc2); // union

Console.WriteLine(sc); // prints: [red,blue,green]
```

Comment: what would be your techniq say you need Dict.add(color , color),  than also Dict.Add(Style.fontfamily, afont) , will you keep them all in one set (...values many types). try it , how will you implement the aproach

Comment: best way is to use a class then..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444013/c-access-enum-from-another-class

Comment: going through some of the code in *your* link remindes me of a solution i have made on controls to have one method to accept set both webcontrols and htmlcontrols that are derived from same Control Type class, though has different properties , i was filtering then any parameter to check it's type so if it is this type do this, the other, do that . nice example but i said, in a scenario(tipical) when you need to set both font and color properties, using same dictionary dicrionary could be then set to defults parameters, i'll update my post ,could u check with me few minutes from now i'll show u

Comment: just an idea i thought , i was writing that last comment here while not looking at the method , but wait i know

Comment: 2 dictionaries , i forgot  the idea , though what about types @Jason Was mentioning , now it remindes me DynamicStyle_Generator<T>()