# How to assign instance with Enum serialization attribute

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum defined

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public enum MyEnum
{
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Big Band")]
    BigBand
 }
```

Now i have to initialize one object with enum value Big Band.
How do i do this.
I get this value from xml so i cant change this. 
If i have to initialize with BigBand, i was using Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), value) which was working without any issues but now i am getting error like Big Band does not exist in enum.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far?

Comment: I tried setting like below

Comment: Employee employee=new Employee(); employee.enum=9MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), Big Band)

Comment: I think this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444013/c-access-enum-from-another-class