# How can I get access of a enum in a script from another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script with the enum :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum InteractableMode // your custom enumeration
    {
        Description,
        Action
    };

    public InteractableMode interactableMode = InteractableMode.Description;

    public float distance;

    private bool action = true;

    [TextArea(1, 10)]
    public string description = "";

    public void ActionOnItem()
    {
        if(interactableMode == InteractableMode.Action && distance <= 5f && action == true)
        {


            action = false;
        }
    }
}
```

and the script I'm trying to access from :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class IKControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InteractableItem[] lookObj = null;
    public GameObject objToThrow;
    public Text text;
    public Text textMultiLine;
    public float weightDamping = 1.5f;
    public float maxDistance = 10f;
    public bool RightHandToTarget = true;
    public float throwSpeed;

    private List<InteractableItem> allDetectedItems;
    private Animator animator;
    private InteractableItem lastPrimaryTarget;
    private Quaternion savedRotation;
    private float lerpEndDistance = 0.1f;
    private float finalLookWeight = 0;
    private bool transitionToNextTarget = false;
    private InteractableItem target;
    private bool throwObj = false;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        allDetectedItems = new List<InteractableItem>();
    }

    // Callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (lookObj != null)
        {
            InteractableItem primaryTarget = null;
            float closestLookWeight = 0;

            // Here we find the target which is closest (by angle) to the players view line
            allDetectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (InteractableItem target in lookObj)
            {
                Vector3 lookAt = target.transform.position - transform.position;
                lookAt.y = 0f;

                // Filter out all objects that are too far away
                //if (lookAt.magnitude > maxDistance) continue;
                if (lookAt.magnitude > target.distance) continue;

                float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0f, transform.forward.z).normalized, lookAt.normalized);
                float lookWeight = Mathf.Clamp(dotProduct, 0f, 1f);
                if (lookWeight > 0.1f && lookWeight > closestLookWeight)
                {
                    closestLookWeight = lookWeight;
                    primaryTarget = target;
                    allDetectedItems.Add(target);
                }
            }

            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                if ((lastPrimaryTarget != null) && (lastPrimaryTarget != primaryTarget) && (finalLookWeight > 0f))
                {
                    // Here we start a new transition because the player looks already to a target but
                    // we have found another target the player should look at
                    transitionToNextTarget = true;
                }
            }

            // The player is in a neutral look position but has found a new target
            if ((primaryTarget != null) && !transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                lastPrimaryTarget = primaryTarget;
                //finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, closestLookWeight, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 1f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(primaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = primaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 1f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);

                    // -> new code block
                    if (finalLookWeight > 0.95f) // here you can play with a value between 0.95f -> 1.0f
                    {
                        // call your funtion to shoot something here
                        throwObj = true;
                        target = primaryTarget;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Let the player smoothly look away from the last target to the neutral look position
            if ((primaryTarget == null && lastPrimaryTarget != null) || transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 0f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.5f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);
                }

                if (finalLookWeight < lerpEndDistance)
                {
                    transitionToNextTarget = false;
                    finalLookWeight = 0f;
                    lastPrimaryTarget = null;
                }
            }

            // Show primary object found by the player
            if (primaryTarget != null) text.text = "Item found: " + primaryTarget.description;
            else text.text = "Item found: none";

            // Show all objects found by the player
            if (allDetectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                string result = "";
                foreach (InteractableItem item in allDetectedItems)
                {
                    result += item.description + "\n";
                }
                textMultiLine.text = result;
            }
            else
            {
                textMultiLine.text = "No items found.";
            }
        }
    }

    private void ThrowObject()
    {
        if(target.interactableMode.)
        objToThrow.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objToThrow.transform.position, target.transform.position, throwSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (throwObj == true)
        {
            ThrowObject();
        }
    }
}
```

At the bottom in the method ThrowObject I want it to throw the object only if the object enum mode is set to Action :

```
private void ThrowObject()
        {
            if(target.interactableMode.)
            objToThrow.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objToThrow.transform.position, target.transform.position, throwSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
```

The problem is I have a access to the variable target.interactableMode in the IF but not to the enum it self. I want to check if the target is in action mode then throw the object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: Access Enum from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444013/c-access-enum-from-another-class). You should probably just move your enum to it's own NameSpace / .cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enum is inside a class, so to call her, you have to call the class first, then the enum:
YourClass.YourEnum

In your case:
InteractableItem.InteractableMode

And for access a value in this enum:
InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action